# How to cast uint8_t * to jbyteArray jni android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am working on an Android library that uses some c/c++ code.

I apparently have some sort of coding error that only happens to error out on runtime.

The error: `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x7d61e62000`

This is the JNI code I am using to call the C code.

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_comp_complibrary_api_initializeProduct(JNIEnv *env, jobject 
                                                    instance,
                                                    jbyteArray buffer_) {
    jbyte *buffer = env->GetByteArrayElements(buffer_, NULL);

    jbyteArray rv = (jbyteArray) initializeProduct((uint8_t *) buffer);

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(buffer_, buffer, 0);

    return rv;
}
```

`initializeProduct` returns a `uint8_t *`.

If I understand things correctly then I should be able to cast the return value to a `jbyteArray` and then be able to assign that to a `byte[]` in one of my java classes. However, this is not the case.

```
byte[] defend = (byte[]) initializeProduct(bufferByteArray);
```

You will notice that a `jbyteArray` can be cast to a `uint8_t *` as I am passing one in as a parameter to `initializeProduct`. Stepping through the c code I can confirm this to be true.

What is the correct way to convert/cast `uint8_t *` to `jbyteArray`?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Jarvis See the accepted answer. I believe I did exactly that. Initialize a new byte array with `NewByteArray()` and set them with `SetByteArrayRegion()` and assign the variables. Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. It isn't a casting operation. You have to create a Java byte array object, with [`NewByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#New_PrimitiveType_Array_routines), and set the elements using the raw C data via [`SetByteArrayRegion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Set_PrimitiveType_ArrayRegion_routines).

> You will notice that a jbyteArray can be cast to a uint8_t * as I am passing one in as a parameter to `initializeProduct()`

*Non sequitur.* Just because you can cast something doesn't imply that it actually becomes that. You need to use `GetByteArrayElements()`  or `GetByteArrayRegion()` to get the data out of the `jbyteArray` for your C code, followed by the appropriate `ReleaseXXX()` call when done.

Answer (score 3):

Similar code in chromium source: [ToJavaByteArray()](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/android/jni_array.cc), hope these code can help you.

```java
ScopedJavaLocalRef<jbyteArray> ToJavaByteArray(JNIEnv* env,
                                               const uint8_t* bytes,
                                               size_t len) {
  jbyteArray byte_array = env->NewByteArray(len);
  CheckException(env);
  DCHECK(byte_array);
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(
      byte_array, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(bytes));
  CheckException(env);
  return ScopedJavaLocalRef<jbyteArray>(env, byte_array);
}
```